# Sharing sessions between rails 3.1 and 2.3.12 using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I'm attempting to share sessions between a rails 3.1 app and rails 2.3.12 app. The rails 3.1 app is a subdomain of the 2.3.12 app. Both apps use devise for authentication (different versions for rails compatibility).

I've managed to get it working to the point where session variables are accessible from either app, but it fails after sign in. It seems the reason it fails is because `session[:session_id]` gets reset on sign in, leaving the other app with the old session_id.

How can sessions continue to be shared after sign in? I've attempted to prevent devise from resetting the session_id but couldn't see where that was happening.

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs on  [Rails sessions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions) specially "2.5 Session Storage".

You need to save the sessions and probably you'll need to have the same keys on both applications.

Comment: I'm using the same key, secret and domain for both apps. I can see cookies generated by the other app until signing in (devise resets the session id). Are you suggesting that switching to database-stored sessions instead of cookie-stored will resolve this?

Comment: Yes! Also check thhis screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3 that should help you.

Comment: Switching to active_record_store didn't seem to help. The sessions are in sync between apps until signing in.